# Does a non deterministic turing machine that guesses a password of fixed length eventually halt and accept?

Tags: automata, turing-machines

So the password is of length 5 and can be made up of any digits 0-9.

I have a non deterministic turing machine M1 that does the following:

- Takes any of my inputs that meets the above requirements and converts it to random numbers.
- In other words it generates random passwords of lengths 5, so I can give it 00000, but it will convert it to another random number like: 43251.

And another deterministic turing machine M2 that does the following:

- Only halts and accept on the input of 12345
- Loops forever on any other number

**If I connect M1 and M2 together, so M1 generates a number and passes it to M2, does this new machine always halt?**

I'm confused as I'm not sure if the machine will keep trying numbers or just end up stuck in the loop forever. I remember for Non-deterministic Finite Machines an input is considered to be accepted if it finds 1 path to an accepting state, but I'm not sure about this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:**  Every nondeterministic Turing machine has an equivalent deterministic Turing machine.

Connecting the Non-deterministic TM $M_1$ with Deterministic TM $M_2$ gives you a Deterministic TM $M$ using the above theorem.

What you are asking is the equivalent of ***will M halt for an input $i$***. This is the halting problem which is undecidable.

Comment: Oh I see. The follow up question asks: For what input does the new machine halt? How would I know this as M1 changes the input that I initially pass it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not decidable. Your input is $5$. You cannot predict the random output of $M_1$ and hence the halting of the overall machine $M$ is undecidable.

Comment: @ThunderBase I think it depends on the denotation of *undecidable*.  If you consider 1 Test as M1 sending M2 up to $10^{(10)}$ numbers, and checking whether M2 stops before M1 stops, it is clear that in well over 95% of the tests, M2 will stop before M1 stops.

Comment: I'm not sure. From the question I found, all it says is that the input I give M1, will then be converted to a different number non-deterministically. This is then passed to M2.